# Google maps - current location - no HTML5

Tags: html, google-maps

I am using google maps on a simple HTML website. I can center the map on user's current location using HTML5, but that requires getting permission from the user.
Now, when I go to maps.google.com, the map is centered around my location pretty accurately, without asking my permission.
How can I do that? When I define the map in my HTML webpage, I need to identify the center. How can I set the center to the center that google maps automatically finds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming your in chrome go to the google maps page, then press f12 goto the resources tab, expand local storage, session storage and cookies, delete all entries from there, close the tab, go back to maps, notice it will no longer have your location, you'll need to click on the sniper type gps icon and it will ask you in you browser if you want to allow location.

answer being it has to ask you for permission, there is no compromise whether it's google or anyone else.

Comment: I did what you said (cleared local storage, session storage and cookies), but it still finds exactly where I am. What am I missing?

Comment: that's what i did and it worked, try clearing your cache, there is no where else it could be holding it, it strictly against privacy laws to get location without permission. ( just tried it again works no issue, highlight entries and delete, my chrome version is 35.0.1916.153 http://whatversion.net/chrome/ ......using google maps https://www.google.co.uk/maps

Answer (score 1):

Your only other option, if you are serving any content server-side, would be to attempt to get the user's location from his or her IP address. There are a handful of APIs and services out there that will give you approximate locations, but your mileage may vary greatly. And, as I mentioned, you would have to execute that code server-side and then return some lat-long back to the client side to initialize/update your map.

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to do that. Can you recommend any API (I'm doing Ruby on Rails) that I can use to find approximate location from IP address on the server-side?